# Parse HTML or Plain Text File and return the text delimited by a string

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, preg-match-all

I need help in parsing a text file. This text file has a few html tags in it. What I am looking for is a Solution (Either in PHP or JS or both) which will strip all these, and store the output into separate variables.

```
  Integration/QA  
<http://shopfloor/sfweb/secure/CancelOrders>


  Development  
<http://shopfloor/sfweb/secure/CancelOrders>


------------------------------------------------------------------------

*HEADER INFO*
    *View Object:* 6541997  *BPO:* 0020064484   *Ack Date:* 2012-05-25
    *Operation(s):* PS_Queue, PS_BoxAll, JPN_End

------------------------------------------------------------------------

*EXTERNAL ORDER NUMBER REFERENCE*
*SAP Sales Order Number*    *Customer P.O. Number*  *Legacy Order Number*
0310407774      89FC37763001

------------------------------------------------------------------------

*PRODUCTS FOR THIS WORK OBJECT/OPERATION(S)*
*PL*    *Product #*     *Qty*   *Options*   *Serial #*
LN  AE241A  1        

------------------------------------------------------------------------

*Station Info*
*Start Station:* JPN_End    *Location:* Done    *Station:*
*Birth Date/Time:* 2012-05-22 08:26:17 SGT  *Power Cord:*   *Voltage:*

------------------------------------------------------------------------

*MATERIAL LIST FOR THIS WORK OBJECT/OPERATION(S)*
*Part Number*   *Qty*   *Description*   *BB Type*   *Material
Location*   *Serial Number*
AE241-90001     1   XP Remote Support Service Leaflet   BOM     PACK     


Privacy Statement
```

I basically Want to strip a few text from this code into php variables, so it will return:

```
$viewobject = "6541997"
$BPO = "0020064484"
$ackdate = "2012-05-25"
$operations = "PS_Queue, PS_BoxAll, JPN_End"
$sapSO = "0310407774"
$legacyON = "89FC37763001"
$pl = "LN"
$product = "AE241A"
$qty = 1;
$startstn = "JPN_end"
$location = "Done"
$bdate = "PS_Queue, PS_BoxAll, JPN_End"
$pn = "AE241-90001"
$qty = 1;
$description =" XP Remote Support Service Leaflet";
```

and the like. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

```
preg_match_all('/\*(view object|bpo|ack date):\*\s+([0-9\-]+)/i', $text, $m);

// $m contains matches, try to print_r($m)

$viewobject = $m[2][0];  // 6541997
$bpo = $m[2][1];         // 0020064484
$ackdate = $m[2][2];     // 2012-05-25
```

Comment: Thanks @bsdnoobz! It worked. However, how do i get the other variables? I don't really understand how the code worked.

Basically i need to fetch a few more date from the text file.
`code` $sapSON = 0310407774;
`code` $legacyON = 89FC37763001;
`code` $pl = LN;
`code` $product = AE241A;

and all the other info.. thank you!